# How to execute synchronous cv2 in async app?

Tags: python, opencv, async-await, python-asyncio, threadpool

Im here with stupid question, but google and chats said they doesnt know how to solve that.

In async app i need to start recording video from webcam by funcion call. While recording is in progress i need to execute some code, and when it’s done - to stop recording by another call.

My issue is in that im using cv2 to record video, and it’s synchronous.
i.e. recording blocks whole event loop. And this is not the way i need it to work)

Does anybody knows how to deal with that or maybe have an experience in solving simmilar issue?
  I tried to create a class to bring the flag out from blocking function
 and call my recording function with `ThreadPoolExecutor`.
To be precise:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
        result = await loop.run_in_executor(
            pool, self.recording)
```

In this case if `record` is an async function, im getting ‘courutine was never awaited’ exception, which is fine because `threadpoolexecutor` shouldn’t work with async functions. But. If `record` is a default synchronous  function, it blocks event loop as if i called it directly

Here's the full code:

```
from cv2 import cv2 as cv
import requests
import time
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
from datetime import datetime
# from tmp.room import room

cam = cv.VideoCapture(0)  # 0 -> index of camera
width = int(cam.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH) + 0.5)
height = int(cam.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT) + 0.5)
size = (width, height)
# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
# out = cv.VideoWriter(f'{room}.avi', fourcc, 10.0, size, 1)
out = cv.VideoWriter(f'output.avi', fourcc, 10.0, size, 1)


class CameraControls(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = True

    def recording(self):
        while True:
            ret, frame = cam.read()
            out.write(frame)

            if not self.flag:
                break
        cam.release()
        out.release()
        cv.destroyAllWindows()

    async def do_test(self):
        self.flag = True
        _loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        result = await _loop.run_in_executor(None, self.recording)
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        self.flag = False


async def read_and_send_vid(barcode, auth_token):
    name = f"{barcode}-{str(datetime.today().timestamp()).split('.')[0]}"
    url = f"url/{name}.avi"
    head = {
        "X-Auth-Token": auth_token,
        "Content-Type": "video/x-msvideo",
    }
    async with open('output.avi', mode='rb') as file:
        response = requests.post(url=url, head=head, files=file)
        if response.status_code == 201:
            return name

cl1 = CameraControls()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(cl1.do_test())
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, executors are the answer - just that `asyncio` already have the proper wrappers to start the pool and run your function:

```
...
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
await loop.run_in_executor(None, sync_function, *args)
```

> I'm sure this should work. Unfortunately this is the actual way im
> trying to run my code (you can find it in do_test() function in my
> full code snippet. Am i doing something wrong?

Yes.Async code has the caracteristic that you can write parallel code that behave as if it were serial, in the sense you have full control of where your code could be interrupted by parallel tasks. This have big advantages in avoiding most traps of concurrent programming: very little need for mechanisms like locks, semaphores.

On the down side, you are responsible to actually ensure anything you want in parallel to be in parallel: whenever you make use of "await", you code will just continue on the next line when the awaited task finishes. Meanwhile, other scheduled tasks may run. In this case, this means that the line after calling `run_in_executor`, that does `await sleep`, is only reached when the recording is over.

What you want in this case is to schedule the `run_in_executor` with a
"create_task"  call on the loop, not await for it:

```
    async def do_test(self):
        self.flag = True
        _loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        _loop.create_task(_loop.run_in_executor(None, self.recording))
        # Now the task created in the call above starts running in the
        # moment the current co-routine is paused in the call bellow:
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        self.flag = False
```

Other ways of forcing code to run in parallel include use `asyncio.gather` to actually start more than one co-routine in parallel - let' s suppose you need the  `read_and_send_vid` code aboce to run along the recording in the other function:

```
loop.run_until_complete(
    asyncio.gather(
        read_and_send_vid(...), 
        CameraControls().do_test()
))
```

Comment: Im sure this should work. Unfortunately this is the actual way im trying to run my code (you can find it in `do_test()` function in my full code snippet. Am i doing something wrong?